# use of callback in Java

Tags: callback

I am writing application for generating graphs using jfree.A combo box is provided for selecting a particular graph.I have maintained different classes for different graphs.And am using switch statement to call those particular class on selecting a type of graph.Now i want to eliminate this switch and make it work dynamic . for e.g if a new graph class is written on selection of that graph i should be able to call that class instead of writing one more case in switch.Will the callback in Java help for this.If yes how? also is there any other method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want here is an `Interface`.  As in, a common API that any `Graph` instance is guaranteed to provide.  Then you don't need to worry about specifically what kind of graph was selected, because every graph exposes the same callback API.  For instance, you might have something like:

```
public interface Selectable {
    public void onSelect();
}
```

And then an abstract `Graph` class that you use as the superclass for your graph implementations, like:

```
public abstract class Graph implements Selectable {
}
```

Then you just mark each graph implementation with `extends Graph` and the compiler will make sure that you implement `onSelect()` in each one.  Once that's done then your `switch` statement can be replaced with a call to the graph's `onSelect()` method.

Doing true dynamic callbacks/method invocations on completely arbitrary objects is possible in Java by using reflection and the `Method` class, but it is really not straightforward and is kind of overkill for what it sounds like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern is what you are looking for. It's massively used in event-driven UI code.